# What column type should UUID be in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I would like to use UUIDs has my primary key, and I am generating them using the built-in `gen_random_uuid()` expression for `DEFAULT`.

However, I don't know what column type to use for UUIDs. When I use `uuid` or `UUID`, I get the following error:

> PostgreSQL said: column "id" cannot be cast automatically to type uuid
> Hint: You might need to specify "USING id::uuid".

Is there a native UUID column type? Should I just be using varchar(255)?

Thanks.

Comment: `uuid` **is** the correct type for such a column. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete SQL statement that causes this error as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please.

Comment: See the documentation for [UUID Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-uuid.html).

Comment: I found what was going wrong. I had an existing column that I was trying to edit that was already set to a data type of, say, varchar(255). When I tried to alter the data type to uuid, it said that varchar(255) couldn't be automatically casted (think "converted') to uuid. But when I created a whole new column from the ground up with uuid as the column type, it worked fine with uuid as the type!

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL supports a UUID data type 'out of the box' indeed: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the id cannot be cast automatically because it has to be generated. Remember when id is numbered and automatically incremented but uuid uses uuid-ossp to generate it. I would just leave the id and create a new column for the uuid (change it to primary) and reference it for foreign relation. This way I still don't lose my id. In this example, you need to put the table_name and new_column_name as per your case but never call this column uuid

> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN new_column_name UUID DEFAULT (uuid_generate_v4());

Note: You cannot name your new column id because it will clash with the id (int) unless you want to drop this column which I would not advice especially if you have relationships setup.

References:

[Functions for UUID generation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html#id-1.11.7.58.6)

[The Basics of PostgreSQL UUID Data Type](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-uuid/)

[Should I call my UUID primary key column ID or not?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311277/should-i-call-my-uuid-primary-key-column-id-or-not#:%7E:text=You%20shouldn%27t%20ascribe%20meaning%20to%20your%20surrogate%20keys,so%20I%20stick%20with%20calling%20them%20ID%20%E2%81%B0.)